# Excel worksheet pages print

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so i've got 2 worksheets, first one containing one page with a table specifying names/ID/.. of certain people, the second worksheet contains multiple pages, each page concerning one of those said people from the first page's table. (if we have 5 people in the first worksheet's table, there will be 5 pages in the second worksheet).

Each one of those people have a command button near their names that should allow me the print out the specific page concerning this person, and that's where i am stuck...

is there a way to manipulate pages (using VBA coding) in a worksheet? and is there a way to control what you can print?

all help is well appreciated, and thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pages property. You can set the PrintArea though. You can also set which pages you want to print and what printer to use.

```
'set print area
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$B$12"

'clear print area
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

'print worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.PrintOut
```

Checkout the properties for `ws.PrintOut`. There are lots of things you can do in code. Try recording a macro and see how the macro does it for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just press **ALT+F11** to open VBA editor and take a look at the code behind. From there you can modify the code as per your requirements. Rgds,

Comment: Yeh i already know that, my question is, are there any proprieties for pages inside a worksheet?

Comment: You should analyze the VBA code they use for printing. Please, narrow down your question to some specifics. Rgds

Comment: Ok, the ultimate question here is how do i use the Printout command to print a specific page that contains a certain number?

Comment: You'll need to determine the range to print using Range.Find or some other method then set the print area. I suggest you start another question with more specifics.